# how can i remove the line width in canvas in html with javascript when i click thick brush button

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to remove the line width when i click thick brush button but it didn't work there are different condition in this draw condition based on what button you click and i'm removing the blur and shadowcolor in erasecanvas but itsn't working. i'm changing the drawing design based on button. i'm changing the drawing design based on button

```
        var spray = false;
        var glowwrite = false;
        var eraseCnavas = false;
        var newLineWidth;
        var newColor = 'black';

        thickbrush.addEventListener('click', function () {
            spray = true;
            eraseCnavas = false;
            glowwrite = false;
        });
        glow.addEventListener('click', function () {
            spray = false;
            eraseCnavas = false;
            glowwrite = true;

            erase.classList.remove('glowbrush');
        })
        erase.addEventListener('click', function () {
            eraseCnavas = true;
            spray = false;
            eraseCnavas = false;
            brushname.innerHTML = 'Eraser';
        })
        var clientX, clientY, timeout;


        function draw(e) {

            if (painting) {

                previous = {
                    x: mouse.x,
                    y: mouse.y
                };
                mouse = oMousePos(canvas, e);
                // saving the points in the points array
                points.push({
                    x: mouse.x,
                    y: mouse.y,
                    color: newColor,
                    lineWidth: newLineWidth
                })
                console.log('pushing to pints length = ' + points.length);
                if (eraseCnavas) {
                    c.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
                    c.shadowBlur = 0;
                    c.shadowColor = none;
                }
                if (glowwrite) {
                    c.shadowBlur = 10;
                    c.shadowColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
                }
                if (spray) {
                    c.lineCap = 'round';
                    newColor = 'none';
                    newLineWidth= 0;
                    timeout = setTimeout(spraying, 50);
                }
                // drawing a line from the previous point to the current point.
                c.beginPath();
                c.moveTo(previous.x, previous.y);
                c.strokeStyle = newColor;
                c.lineWidth = newLineWidth; 
                c.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                c.stroke();
            }

        }

        function spraying() {
            console.log('timeout called');

            var density = 30;

            clientX = mouse.x;
            clientY = mouse.y;
            for (var i = density; i--;) {
                var angle = getRandomFloat(0, Math.PI * 2);
                var radius = getRandomFloat(0, 20);
                c.fillRect(
                    clientX + radius * Math.cos(angle),
                    clientY + radius * Math.sin(angle),
                    1, 1);
            }
            if (!timeout) return;
            timeout = setTimeout(sparying, 5000);
        }
```

i want when you click on spray button the should be removed and only spray will show and when you click on erase it should remove the shadow color and shadow blur from line itself i'm removing but it's not working

Comment: Could you please post a working example of your code? It's a bit hard to see what it's doing without all the needed functions.

Comment: sure here my code pen https://codepen.io/Naveen-kashyap/pen/areeWL all my problems are there look when u click spray button and paint and then click glow then then erase the canvas with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt at combining styles into a terminal effect (`spray`, `glow`, `erase`, etc) has led to the problem you've encountered.

Your code in pseudo says this:

1. **if** `eraseCnavas` is `true` **then**

   - change styles

AND

2. **if** `glowwrite` is `true`, **then**

   - change styles (*potentially undoing the ability to erase anything*)

AND

3. **if** `spray` is `true` **then**

   - change styles (*removing ability to erase, but never removing `glow`*)
   - draw a spray pattern
4. Finally, **in all cases**

   - draw the line with those styles (*why the line draws regardless of tool*)

Ordinarily, choosing a tool leads to a `switch` statement or an `if/else if/else` construct that ensures the correct tool is being used.

I recommend you refactor your `draw()` function so that it:

**Either** draws a line
**OR** draws a glowing line
**OR** sprays a line

rather than trying to combine effects for the correct outcome.

Comment: its's working fine but when i click on glow and then click on erase it don't erase instead it do the glow thing i have updated the codepen u can see there